# Is there a better solution to cURL this JSON?

Tags: json, bash, for-loop, curl, jq

I have this function that iterates over the keys of a given JSON using `curl` and `jq` as the JSON processor, My code looks like this : (bash)

```
function getJSONContent {
  option=""

  for option in "header" "developer" "category" "description"
  do
    content=$(curl -s $extension_url | jq ".[\"$extension\"][\"$option\"]")
    printf "$content\n"
  done
}
```

But the problem is that it curl's 4 time and I haven't found a better solution to this without getting an error.

**Is doing this okay? Or is there just a better solution to do this in Bash / Shellscript?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there just a better solution ... ?

Yes!

1. You evidently only need one call to curl and one to jq, but at the very
   least, you should avoid calling curl more than once.
2. Avoid constructing the jq command "on the fly".  Instead, you can pass in the shell (or environment) variables
   on the command line, e.g. using --arg or --argjson
3. In this specific case, it looks like you can avoid calling jq more than once by simply using jq's ',' operator.

In brief, try something along the following lines:

```
 curl -s "$extension_url" |
   jq --arg extension "$extension" '
     .[$extension]["header","developer","category","description"]'
```